# Numeral domains in Haskell

Tags: math, haskell

Haskell is more mathematical than many languages because of lambda-calculus, but I think the domains are incomplete for number: we have `Integer` and `Float`, for example, but not `Positive` or `Negative`, or `[1..5]` as a domain.
This sometimes makes functions unsafe while the compiler could have catched the type error. For example: `5`mod`0` outputs `*** Exception: divide by zero` at run-time only.
`mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a` but we could have something like `mod :: Integral a, a != 0 => a -> a -> a`; something like a guard or an interval or another datatype... In a game, I want my character to have a positive number  for its life. Or from 0 to 100, not under, not upper. When he gets hit, I need to call the ugly `positive x = if x > 0 then x else 0`. Even C has `signed` and `unsigned`.

Is it a weakness or are they reasons why there are no "interval" domains? Is there a package fixing this?

Comment: I'm afraid you may have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: You can often make the types you describe by wrapping other numeric types and providing safe constructors. Is that what you want?

Comment: Added :). Plus, there are TWO questions.

Comment: @gspr How would you do that? Using a `Maybe (Num a)`? It's a little bothersome if you want to use it on `mod` for example.

Comment: @gspr that works well for many things, but a numerical type that's not a `Num` instance is really awkward. And once it is `Num`, there's no way to prevent e.g. negative numbers at compile-time.

Comment: Some of those would require something like a dependent type system to work (as, for example, you'd need to be able to prove at compile time that the second argument to `mod` isn't 0, unless you don't want your type to have subtraction).

Comment: My main annoyance is that `fromInteger` is not `fromNatural`, even though the compiler only ever calls it with positive numbers.

Comment: @L01man: I agree, the `Num` class is a bit annoying in itself. And Wiklund also rightfully points out that some of the things you mention can't be done (at least not in a truly satisfactory way) without dependent types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're free to make such classes, but perhaps the reason why they weren't included in Haskell was because people couldn't find a way to make them **frequently** useful.

It's quite clear you want subtraction with your class, but you also want it to be closed.

Something like this maybe?

```
NonNegative x - NonNegative y = NonNegative (max (x - y) 0)
```

But then the identity `x - y + y == x` does not hold.

People have made alternative numeric hierarchies for Haskell, such as ['Numeric Prelude'](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude). Haskell is quite friendly to customization, you can even replace the Prelude with your own definitions, but whether they're useful and don't cause more problems than they solve is another matter.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're looking for a dependently typed language like Agda, Idris, or Coq.

You're right, it would be nice to have restricted numeric types, but you need to think about how you would use those types, as well. Let's say you had your type for `mod` that excluded a `0` value. Now you need to call it in your program. If the number is a literal, presumably it's "easy" for the compiler to determine that it's not `0` and let you call the function, but what if the number was provided at runtime, possibly from user input or some complicated procedure? You'd need some way to explain to the compiler that you know that the number will not be `0` when you pass it into `mod`. Haskell doesn't really have the facilities to do that in any easy way (there are annoying ways like reflecting all values into the type system) and that's why you don't see more precise types.

Comment: It's the same problem as when for example users provide `5.4` or even `"lol"` when you want an `Int`. I'll check these languages out to find ideas.

Comment: It wouldn't be that complicated to ensure `>0`, you'd just need to allow only positive literals, addition and multiplication, but no subtraction.

Comment: @leftaroundabout restricting the operations prevents many legitimate operations. I can subtract just fine, as long as my final result is not 0. If the number comes from user input, I can't guarantee that it's not going to be 0.